# How to use pcl::transformPoint() in PCL 1.8 Compile Error, working in PCL 1.7

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to transform a Point using pcl::transformPoint(my_point, my_affine) to transform the point my_point. However when trying to compile the following code using catkin_make I get a compile error under lubuntu 18.04, ros melodic (which uses pcl 1.8.1). When trying to compile the exact same code under ubuntu 16.04 with ros kinetic (which uses pcl 1.7.2) my code example compiles and can be executed without any problem.

I don't know why the code is not working under melodic/PCL 1.8 and what I have to change.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/common/transforms.h>
#include <matrixHandling.h>

int main(){
    pcl::PointXYZ my_point;
    Eigen::Affine3d my_affine;
    Matrix4d my_matrix;

    my_point=  pcl::PointXYZ(1,2,3);
    std::cout << my_point << std::endl;
    my_matrix << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1;
    my_affine.matrix() = my_matrix;
    std::cout << my_affine.matrix()<< std::endl;

    my_point = transformPoint(my_point, my_affine);
    std::cout << my_point << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following compile error under ros melodic/ PCL 1.8.1:

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:419:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/StdVector:14,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/common/transforms.h:42,
                 from /home/admin/catkin_ws/src/project/cpp/tools/transforming.cpp:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h: In instantiation of ‘struct Eigen::internal::traits<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:115:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::internal::dense_product_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0, 3>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:147:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0, Eigen::Dense>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:71:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:1390:72:   required from ‘static Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::ResultType Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::run(const TransformType&, const MatrixType&) [with TransformType = Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2>; MatrixType = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>]’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:442:80:   required from ‘const typename Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>, OtherDerived>::ResultType Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>::operator*(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; _Scalar = double; int _Dim = 3; int _Mode = 2; int _Options = 0; typename Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>, OtherDerived>::ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>]’
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/common/impl/transforms.hpp:319:37:   required from ‘PointT pcl::transformPoint(const PointT&, const Eigen::Transform<Scalar, 3, 2>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; Scalar = double]’
/home/admin/catkin_ws/src/project/cpp/tools/transforming.cpp:17:55:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:29:127: error: no type named ‘ReturnType’ in ‘struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<double, float, Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<double, float> >’
   typedef typename ScalarBinaryOpTraits<typename traits<LhsCleaned>::Scalar, typename traits<RhsCleaned>::Scalar>::ReturnType Scalar;
                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:415:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/StdVector:14,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/common/transforms.h:42,
                 from /home/admin/catkin_ws/src/project/cpp/tools/transforming.cpp:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:48:34:   required from ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:115:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::internal::dense_product_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0, 3>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:147:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0, Eigen::Dense>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:71:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:1390:72:   required from ‘static Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::ResultType Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::run(const TransformType&, const MatrixType&) [with TransformType = Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2>; MatrixType = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>]’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:442:80:   required from ‘const typename Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>, OtherDerived>::ResultType Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>::operator*(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; _Scalar = double; int _Dim = 3; int _Mode = 2; int _Options = 0; typename Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>, OtherDerived>::ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>]’
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/common/impl/transforms.hpp:319:37:   required from ‘PointT pcl::transformPoint(const PointT&, const Eigen::Transform<Scalar, 3, 2>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; Scalar = double]’
/home/admin/catkin_ws/src/project/cpp/tools/transforming.cpp:17:55:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:83:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::coeff’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::coeff;
                 ^~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:84:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::coeffByOuterInner’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::coeffByOuterInner;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:85:26: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::operator()’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::operator();
                          ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:86:26: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::operator[]’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::operator[];
                          ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:87:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::x’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::x;
                 ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:88:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::y’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::y;
                 ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:89:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::z’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::z;
                 ^
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseBase.h:90:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}::w’ in ‘Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>, 0>}’
     using Base::w;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:416:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/StdVector:14,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/point_cloud.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/common/transforms.h:42,
                 from /home/admin/catkin_ws/src/project/cpp/tools/transforming.cpp:2:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h: In instantiation of ‘class Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >’:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:115:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::internal::dense_product_base<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0, 3>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:147:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::ProductImpl<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0, Eigen::Dense>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Product.h:71:7:   required from ‘class Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0>’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:1390:72:   required from ‘static Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::ResultType Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::run(const TransformType&, const MatrixType&) [with TransformType = Eigen::Transform<double, 3, 2>; MatrixType = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<TransformType, MatrixType, 2, 1>::ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>]’
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h:442:80:   required from ‘const typename Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>, OtherDerived>::ResultType Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>::operator*(const Eigen::EigenBase<OtherDerived>&) const [with OtherDerived = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>, 0, Eigen::Stride<0, 0> >; _Scalar = double; int _Dim = 3; int _Mode = 2; int _Options = 0; typename Eigen::internal::transform_right_product_impl<Eigen::Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, _Options>, OtherDerived>::ResultType = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>]’
/usr/include/pcl-1.8/pcl/common/impl/transforms.hpp:319:37:   required from ‘PointT pcl::transformPoint(const PointT&, const Eigen::Transform<Scalar, 3, 2>&) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; Scalar = double]’
/home/admin/catkin_ws/src/project/cpp/tools/transforming.cpp:17:55:   required from here
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:75:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}::coeff’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}’
     using Base::coeff;
                 ^~~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:78:17: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}::eval’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}’
     using Base::eval;
                 ^~~~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:81:25: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}::operator*=’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}’
     using Base::operator*=;
                         ^~
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/MatrixBase.h:82:25: error: no members matching ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}::operator/=’ in ‘Eigen::MatrixBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >::Base {aka class Eigen::DenseBase<Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 4, 4>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 1>, 0> >}’
     using Base::operator/=;
                         ^~
project/cpp/CMakeFiles/transforming.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'project/cpp/CMakeFiles/transforming.dir/tools/transforming.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [project/cpp/CMakeFiles/transforming.dir/tools/transforming.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:549: recipe for target 'project/cpp/CMakeFiles/transforming.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [project/cpp/CMakeFiles/transforming.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your pointcloud double precision? Try Matrix4f